# React & ReactQuill: Call methods Inside the Custom Component from toolbar

Tags: reactjs, quill

I have the following piece of code from this demo https://github.com/pc-magas/rwact_quill_call_component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactQuill from 'react-quill';

import '../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css';


const CustomToolbar = () => (
  <div id="toolbar">
    <select className="ql-header">
      <option value="1"></option>
      <option value="2"></option>
      <option selected></option>
    </select>
    <button className="ql-bold"></button>
    <button className="ql-italic"></button>
    <button className="ql-strike"></button>
    <button className="ql-underline"></button>
    <select className="ql-color">
      <option value="red"></option>
      <option value="green"></option>
      <option value="blue"></option>
      <option value="orange"></option>
      <option value="violet"></option>
      <option value="#d0d1d2"></option>
      <option selected></option>
    </select>
    <button className="ql-test">
      <span>Test</span>
    </button>    
  </div>
)

function test(){
  console.log('test');
  //How to call the 
}

/**
 * Basic Editor
 */
class MyEditor extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state={text:''}
    }

    onTextChange(value) { 
        this.setState({text:value})
    }

    addGanhamStyle(){
      const editor = this.reactQuillRef.getEditor();
      const index = editor.getSelection().index || 0;
      editor.insertText(index + 1, 'Ganham Style!!!!');
      editor.insertText(index + 1, '\n');
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <CustomToolbar />
                <ReactQuill
                  ref={(el) => { this.reactQuillRef = el; }}
                  value={this.state.body}
                  onChange={this.handleChange}
                  modules={MyEditor.modules}
                  formats={MyEditor.formats}
                  theme="snow"
                />
             </div>
        )
    }

}

MyEditor.formats = [
  'header', 'font', 'size',
  'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote',
  'list', 'bullet', 'indent',
  'link', 'image', 'color',
]

MyEditor.modules = {
  toolbar: {
    container: "#toolbar",
    'image-tooltip': true,
    'link-tooltip': true,
    handlers:{
      test: test
    }
  }
}

export default MyEditor;
```

What I am trying to do it when the `test` method gets called to call the method `addGanhamStyle` from `MyEditor`. Do you have any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the example repo you linked is a fork of this example: https://codepen.io/alexkrolick/pen/gmroPj (inlined below).

The main point is that the "this context" (lexical scope) of the `test` function will be set at call time, which is why the Codepen example callback has access to `this.quill`, and why the repo example needs to use `bind` in the toolbar handler initialization.

```
/*
 * Custom "star" icon for the toolbar using an Octicon
 * https://octicons.github.io
 */
const CustomButton = () => <span className="octicon octicon-star" />

/*
 * Event handler to be attached using Quill toolbar module (see line 73)
 * https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/toolbar/
 */
function insertStar () {
  const cursorPosition = this.quill.getSelection().index
  this.quill.insertText(cursorPosition, "★")
  this.quill.setSelection(cursorPosition + 1)
}

/*
 * Custom toolbar component including insertStar button and dropdowns
 */
const CustomToolbar = () => (
  <div id="toolbar">
    <select className="ql-header">
      <option value="1"></option>
      <option value="2"></option>
      <option selected></option>
    </select>
    <button className="ql-bold"></button>
    <button className="ql-italic"></button>
    <select className="ql-color">
      <option value="red"></option>
      <option value="green"></option>
      <option value="blue"></option>
      <option value="orange"></option>
      <option value="violet"></option>
      <option value="#d0d1d2"></option>
      <option selected></option>
    </select>    
    <button className="ql-insertStar">
      <CustomButton />
    </button>
  </div>
)

/* 
 * Editor component with custom toolbar and content containers
 */
class Editor extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { editorHtml: '' }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange (html) {
    this.setState({ editorHtml: html });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="text-editor">
        <CustomToolbar />
        <ReactQuill 
          onChange={this.handleChange} 
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
          modules={Editor.modules}
          formats={Editor.formats}
          theme={"snow"} // pass false to use minimal theme
        >
          <div 
            key="editor"                     
            ref="editor"
            className="quill-contents"                     
          />
        </ReactQuill>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

/* 
 * Quill modules to attach to editor
 * See https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/ for complete options
 */
Editor.modules = {
  toolbar: {
    container: "#toolbar",
    handlers: {
      "insertStar": insertStar,
    }
  }
}

/* 
 * Quill editor formats
 * See https://quilljs.com/docs/formats/
 */
Editor.formats = [
  'header', 'font', 'size',
  'bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike', 'blockquote',
  'list', 'bullet', 'indent',
  'link', 'image', 'color',
]

/* 
 * PropType validation
 */
Editor.propTypes = {
  placeholder: React.PropTypes.string,
}

/* 
 * Render component on page
 */
ReactDOM.render(
  <Editor placeholder={'Write something or insert a star ★'}/>, 
  document.querySelector('.app')
)
```